# how to manage cpu resources and synchronise threads in common lisp

Tags: multithreading, common-lisp

I am looking for some advice or good practice about Threads in common lisp. Basically, I am trying to synchronise some threads with a global variable +clock+ (set as a thread too). I am a bit confused about different concepts as join-process, process-wait, make-mutex/make-lock, condition-variable, etc.
I am using ccl and sbcl, so I should probably use [bordeaux-threads](https://common-lisp.net/project/bordeaux-threads/), but this is just a convenient way to manage both.
In short, my code works but when I add a thread, instead to share the cpu resources, this one increases beyond 150%.

```
;; for instance using CCL64 Version 1.12 DarwinX8664
;; --- THREADS-SET-1
(defvar +buffer+ nil)
(defvar +buffer-size+ 30)
(defparameter +compute+
  (ccl:process-preset (ccl:make-process "+compute+")
               #'(lambda ()
               (loop do
                (push (do-some-computation) +buffer+)
                (sleep 0.1)))
               '+compute+))

(defparameter +osc-send+
  (ccl:process-preset (ccl:make-process "+osc-send+")
               #'(lambda ()
               (loop do
                (when +buffer+
                  (OSCsend (car (last +buffer+)))
                  (setf +buffer+ (butlast +buffer+))
                  (if (> (length +buffer+) +buffer-size+)
                      (ccl:process-suspend +compute+)
                      (ccl:process-resume +compute+)))
                (sleep (some-time))))
               '+osc-send+))
;; commands:
(progn
  (ccl:process-enable +compute+)
  (sleep 1)
  (ccl:process-enable +osc-send+))
(progn
  (ccl:process-suspend +compute+)
  (ccl:process-suspend +osc-send+))
(progn
  (ccl:process-resume +compute+)
  (ccl:process-resume +osc-send+))
(progn
  (ccl:process-kill +compute+)
  (ccl:process-kill +osc-send+))

;; when these threads as THREADS-SET-1 are 'playing' dx86cl64 takes more than 90% of cpu
;; and when I add some other threads as THREADS-SET-2, the cpu goes beyond 150%
;; needless to say that I did not try to add a third one before to solve this issue...
```

The final idea is to synchronise THREADS-SET-1 and THREADS-SET-2 with +clock+.
Maybe [lparralel](https://lparallel.org/) can be relevant in that context, if so thanks to illustrate how to use it in that case. Thanks in advance for any help or any reference book to learn about this topic.

Comment: note that when you monitor the cpu usage, if you have 8 cores, you could have percentage over 100% (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145247/understanding-cpu-while-running-top-command)

Comment: there is one too many pair of parentheses around ccl:process-preset, this looks like a function (f) call with something that isn't a function, ie. f = (ccl:process-preset ...); parentheses are meaningful in Lisp

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo mistake.

Comment: I have only 2 cores!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved the issue by making one single thread for each 'routine' plus one for the 'clock'. Then the cpu activity decreased until around 50% for 3 routines.
Anyway, I will be pleased if somebody could explain why in the first example the threads take all that cpu resources and not when I do one thread by routine. I suspect the use of process-suspend/resume instead of mutex... An affair to follow! :)